# Filter fragments manager

Tags: java, android

How could I simplify the `onCreate()` method? Maybe via compact and properly-named methods?

```
public class FilterActivity extends FragmentActivity {    
    private Bundle args;
    private FilterFragment filterFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3_filter);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            args = getIntent().getExtras();
        } else {
            args = savedInstanceState.getBundle(Keys.args);
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        filterFragment = new FilterFragment();
        filterFragment.setArguments(args);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerOfFilterFragment, filterFragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerOfFilterFragment, filterFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        filterFragment = (FilterFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerOfFilterFragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBundle(Keys.args, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this method really a problem? Why are you worried about it? There are some small changes you can make, but they do not have much of an impact on the performance of the routine (if it is slow...).

About the only things I can think of improving are:

1. you check whether the `savedInstanceState` is null twice, and those two checks can be merged in to one...
2. you create a new FilterFragment instance, and you either add it to (if it is not there), or replace it (if there already was one). Thus, you *have* the filterFragement, and you do not need to `findFragmentById(...)` since you should be finding the fragment you just put in there....

Here's your method with the lines commented out that I don't think you need, and also two new lines marked with `//**ADDED**`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3_filter);

    //if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    //    args = getIntent().getExtras();
    //} else {
    //    args = savedInstanceState.getBundle(Keys.args);
    //}

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    filterFragment = new FilterFragment();
    //filterFragment.setArguments(args);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        filterFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());  //**ADDED**
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerOfFilterFragment, filterFragment);
    } else {
        filterFragment.setArguments(savedInstanceState.getBundle(Keys.args));  //**ADDED**
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerOfFilterFragment, filterFragment);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    //filterFragment = (FilterFragment)
    //        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerOfFilterFragment);
}
```